# How to run C++ programs on the web inside a browser?

Tags: c++, web, browser, native

Can one write a program in `C++` and somehow make it run by someone else directly on the web, from a browser, without the other person having to download the .exe?

Comment: It's possible to run C++ programs in a browser using [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/), but it's also possible to run them on a web server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few days ago I would've downvoted this to oblivion and left an unhelpful comment about how little sense that made. Yesterday, however, I read an article on [/r/programming](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/owb4w/the_reality_of_html5_game_development_and_making/) which has led me to now consider your question perfectly valid :). The technology is called Native Client (NaCl):

> Native Client (NaCl for short) is a Chrome specific technology that allows developers to code in C/C++ and produce a .nexe file, a compiled native module. These run inside the NaCl sandbox in Chrome.

The article in question is [here](http://www.photonstorm.com/archives/2759/the-reality-of-html5-game-development-and-making-money-from-it) and is about browser game development, mainly using HTML5.

Comment: Native Client is no longer supported in Chrome, but you can still compile C programs to run in a browser using [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/introducing_emscripten/about_emscripten.html).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it depends on how complex a program you're talking about.

If you're referring to console applications which don't take too long to run, you can always use http://ideone.com/. For example: http://ideone.com/sGw5F

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Native Client.
From http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/:

> Native Client is an open-source technology that allows you to build
>   web applications that seamlessly execute native compiled code inside
>   the browser. This Google Code project is for maintaining the Native
>   Client implementation, including compiler and browser support. If
>   you're writing a compiler, are interested in porting Native Client to
>   a new browser, or are researching the security mechanisms underlying
>   Native Client, you can find useful resources in this project.

Comment: this is so amazing! never knew about this. Do you think this technology will be a killer one? I can see this killing off javafx and java applets and all of that. C++ is more powerful but because one can't run C++ programs in a browser, it is really a pain to have to download dll's and .exe's all the time to run something. It will be much easier to just write some game in C++ and have others run it in a browser like a java applet. Why is no one talking more about this? This is so cool.